# Does $a \equiv b \pmod n$ mean $n \mid a - b$ or  $n \mid b -a$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

If I have 
$a \equiv b \pmod{n}$,
it means
$n \mid b - a$.

But can you write it as
$n \mid a - b$ 
as well?

Comment: $a \equiv b \pmod{n} \implies n \mid (a-b) \implies a-b = nk$ for _some_ integer $k$.  Can you find an integer $m$ such that $b-a = mn$?

Comment: Yes, because in $x$ divides $y$ if and only if $\pm x$ divides $\pm y$, and $a-b = -(b-a)$.

Comment: that would just be -1. but my prof always writes it as b - a

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $\rm\,\ n\ |\ c \iff\ \dfrac{c}{n}\in \mathbb Z \iff -\dfrac{c}{n}\: =\: \dfrac{-c}{n} \in \mathbb Z\ \iff\ n\ |\: {-}c\:.\ $ Now let $\rm\ c = a-b.$

I.e. $\ \mathbb Z$ closed under negation $\rm\: \Rightarrow\ n \mathbb Z\:$ closed under negation, i.e. $\rm\: -(n \mathbb Z)\ =\ (-n) \mathbb Z$

Answer (score 1):

It can be written both ways. 
$$n\mid a-b \iff kn = a-b \iff k'n = b-a \iff n\mid b-a$$
for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ where $k' = -k$. It's just a way of stating that if $n\mid m$ then $n\mid (-m)$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes: $n\mid b-a$ means that there is an integer $k$ such that $b-a = kn$, and $n\mid a-b$ means that there is an integer $\ell$ such that $a-b=\ell n$. Since $a-b=-(b-a)$, these are two ways of saying the same thing: $$b-a = kn\iff a-b=-(b-a)=(-k)n\;.$$